# Find and replace a portion of a string in a txt file

Tags: string, replace, powershell-2.0

Working on a script that takes a FQDN from user input, then enters that server and domain name and adds it to a text file after the pattern `ID=`.

Have a text file and inside is a line that has `ID=[some number]`.
I want to have a cmdlet change the `[some number]` that is found after `ID=` to 2 variables that I defined.

Solution from Ansgar:

```
$name,$domain,$rest = $serverName.split('.',3)
(get-content 'c:\file.txt') -replace "(ID=).*", "`$1$domain$name" | set-content 'c:\file.txt'
```

Using Powershell v2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply replace that number with the content of the variables, then write the text back to the file:

```
(Get-Content 'C:\file.txt') -replace '(ID=)\[\d*\]', "`$1$domain$name" |
    Set-Content 'C:\file.txt'
```